# opening browser bookmarks + ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bookmarks

Interesting dilemma here. I need the ability for users to add links from their browser bookmarks to a field in a Rails form. Basically I would like them to click a button, have it open their browser bookmarks, have them click a link, and it will automatically populate the form field with the bookmark url.

This is a rails / ruby site, but I think the solution may be to go client side with jquery or another javascript library. Is there anything out there you all have been using for similar situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can access a users bookmarks since that seems like a browser-by-browser thing, and also sounds like a security issue. Someone might prove me wrong, though.

Comment: Agreed, not possible - not even by the power of greyskull (javascript)